# Replicate row indices of non-zero entries in a sparse matrix by values of those entries

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

Given a large sparse matrix of integers, I would like to have a list where each element of the list is a vector containing the indices of the non-zero elements in the corresponding row, **replicated by the number times specified by the element**. The matrix is large, and so I need a scalable solution.

Here is an example with working code that is very slow.

```
sparse_matrix <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 2)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    0    2    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    5    0    0


# A very slow attempt that gives the right answer
lapply(seq_len(nrow(sparse_matrix)), function(r) {
  rep(seq_len(ncol(sparse_matrix)), sparse_matrix[r,])
}     )

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 3 3 4
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 4 4 4 4 4
```

**EDIT:** I realize I misspecified my question in the original post -- apologies. Please refer to the above example.

**EDIT 2:** Timing the two solutions for one use case:

```
sparse_matrix <- rsparsematrix (1E4,1E3, 0.01,rand.x = function(n) 1 + round(abs(rnorm(n))))
sparse_matrix <- as.matrix(sparse_matrix)

# 李哲源
ptm <- proc.time()
spM <- as(sparse_matrix, "dgRMatrix")
RowNumber <- rep(1:nrow(spM), diff(spM@p))
ColInd <- split(spM@j + 1, RowNumber)
nze <- split(spM@x, RowNumber)
output <- mapply(rep, ColInd, nze)  
print(proc.time() - ptm)
# 0.232 seconds

#akrun
ptm <- proc.time()
v1 <- c(col(sparse_matrix) * !! sparse_matrix)
v1 <-  setNames(v1, t(row(sparse_matrix)))
output <- rep(v1, sparse_matrix)
print(proc.time() - ptm)
# 1.8 seconds
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you familiar with **compressed row storage** for a sparse matrix? The index you want is just a key component in such storage. R package `Matrix` has its "dgRMatrix" class for this.

```
library(Matrix)
spM <- as(sparse_matrix, "dgRMatrix")
## which row do those non-zero entries lie?
RowNumber <- rep(1:nrow(spM), diff(spM@p))
## position index of those entries on each row, i.e., column index
ColInd <- split(spM@j + 1, RowNumber)
## none-zero-element on each row
nze <- split(spM@x, RowNumber)
## expand position index by matrix value
mapply(rep, ColInd, nze)

#$`1`
#[1] 1 3 3 4

#$`2`
#[1] 4 4 4 4 4
```

---

> If the matrix is stored as a "dgCMatrix", can it be converted to "dgRMatrix"? In that case, the first line gives: no method or default for coercing 'dgCMatrix' to dgRMatrix'

This is no coercing method from "dgCMatrix" to "dgRMatrix". The `sparse_matrix` is as the dense matrix as in your post. So the coercing behind that `as` is from "matrix" to "dgRMatrix".

However, if you already have it as a "dgCMatrix", then you can first transpose it then do something similar on this "dgCMatrix". See below.

```
spM <- as(sparse_matrix, "dgCMatrix")
## transpose
spM <- t(spM)
## which column do those non-zero entries lie?
ColNumber <- rep(1:ncol(spM), diff(spM@p))
## position index of those entries on each column, i.e., row index
RowInd <- split(spM@i + 1, ColNumber)
## none-zero-element on each column
nze <- split(spM@x, ColNumber)
## expand position index by matrix value
mapply(rep, RowInd, nze)

#$`1`
#[1] 1 3 3 4

#$`2`
#[1] 4 4 4 4 4
```

---

Thanks to [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) for his (big) improvement.

For the 1st case with "dgRMatrix",

```
spM <- as(sparse_matrix, "dgRMatrix")
RowNumber <- rep(1:nrow(spM), diff(spM@p))
split(rep(spM@j + 1, spM@x), rep(RowNumber, spM@x))
```

For the 2nd case with "dgCMatrix"

```
spM <- as(sparse_matrix, "dgCMatrix")
ColInd <- rep(1:ncol(spM), diff(spM@p))
split(rep(ColInd, spM@x), rep(spM@i, spM@x))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `which` with `arr.ind` as TRUE to get the row and column index in a `matrix`

```
which(sparse_matrix !=0, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

---

For the second case

```
rep(col(sparse_matrix) * !! sparse_matrix, sparse_matrix)
```

gives a `vector`, but if we need an indentifier, then create a `named` vector

```
v1 <- c(col(sparse_matrix) * !! sparse_matrix)
v1 <-  setNames(v1, t(row(sparse_matrix)))
rep(v1, sparse_matrix)
#1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 
#1 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4
```